# Modal bottom sheet library causing problems

Tags: flutter, dart

I upgraded today my flutter version and found out that problem:

```
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:102:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
      .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:125:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
         ^
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:28:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
      .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:50:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
         ^
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\FlutterSDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1165

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\FlutterSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

It shows up after I am trying to debug it, is there eany solution or I should remove this library?

Comment: Can you provide the code using the library? I think you are importing it twice.

Comment: sadly I can not provide code, becouse project is veary big, and I have no idea where is error, but I will try to find if you are correct with importing it twice

Comment: your modal bottom sheet is already defined. if that is a custom widget, you have to rename it but if that is a library then give an alias name to the import like `import 'package...' as modalSheet`,  something like that.

Comment: @john I realy tried to find any class that whas defined as you said, and I did not had any new library or not to my knowlage, those are my files modyfied to prove, before flutter uptade in monday everything whas kinda working fine, those are my modified files ->

Comment: "       lib/bloc/add_friend/add_friend_bloc.dart
        lib/bloc/add_friend/add_friend_event.dart
        lib/bloc/add_friend/add_friend_state.dart
        lib/bloc/friends_bloc/friends_bloc.dart
        lib/data/api/friends_service.dart
        lib/data/models/post_friends_model.dart
        lib/presentation/app_router.dart
        lib/presentation/screens/account/friends/add_friend_screen.dart
        lib/presentation/screens/account/friends/friends_scanner.dart
        lib/widgets/dialogs.dart
        pubspec.lockpubspec.yaml"

here I have no folders in name of this library

Comment: copy paste this to your vscode search bar  to see all the files that have this import `'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'`
 and replace it with `import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart' as bottomSheet;`

Comment: but I never use any of those, I only use in my project "import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';", when I am trying to add alias ti this import I get warning "Unused import: 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart'.
Try removing the import directive."

Comment: why importing if you never use? if you are not using modal bottom sheet package then remove it from your pubspec.yaml

Comment: But if I remove it I am not able to use "import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';" see the diference, <- this is what I use and, this is what you asumed I am using -> "'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'"  there is "src", I am not using src, but I am using this library

"modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.1.2" this is ofc library that we are talking about

Comment: @john To clarified, I am using "modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.1.2", and In order to use it I am importing "import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';" there is no /src/ inside!, and when I try to give to it some alias I am not able becouse there are some warnings, I follow modal_bottom_sheet library in order to import it, end I am not using /src/ link: https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet/install

Comment: `import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart` give an alias to this import. then revise how you used your bottom sheet ex. if you use it like this `showModalBottomSheet`, change it with `alias.showModalBottomSheet`

Comment: what alias I should give?

Comment: give a relevant alias like `bottomSheet` or what ever relevant to you. as long as it wont conflict to another alias.

Comment: @john well I did as you said, but the error is still there, this is my error: https://codeshare.io/JbBBoR

IN THIS ERROR THERE IS /src/ !!

Comment: did you do it in all the files where you used modal_bottom_sheet? if so, run `flutter clean` on your root project, then `flutter pub get`, then `flutter pub cache repair` then `flutter run`.

Comment: after flutter pub cache repair i got this error: "Deletion failed, path = 'C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\_temp' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
, errno = 2)
pub finished with exit code 66"

Comment: and when I did it again I get "Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
pub finished with exit code 1"

Comment: ouch..it might have some more serious problem than expected.

Comment: ok, I do some magic and I have no idea, but "flutter pub cache repair" worked (I guess), but I have the same error: https://codeshare.io/vwWWyL

"flutter pub cache repair
Reinstalled 274 packages." so I guess it  not send me an error, this time

Comment: my last word is i guess its a problem with the modal bottomsheet. and to test it, try to remove the package, comment all out your bottom modal sheet, clean your project and see if it build. if so, then its a problem from the bottomsheet package. hope you'll resolve that soon.

Comment: ok, I found solution with my friends, I used Flutter beta version, which whas not supportet by this library, and guy who wrote this library has been in the midst of creating new library, not finished yet. My solution whas to change the version to stable and keep in mind that entire library might be change in some time. :D

Comment: so it means your thinking about using 2 same names whas right, new flutter is using the same key words

Answer (score 15):

So this issue is due to name clashes in flutter 3.7 and modal_bottom_sheet:2.1.0

Since flutter 3.7 release this compile time issues started, Library maintainer already published [3.0.0-pre](https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/325#issue-1560921768) version where they rename any `ModalBottomSheetRoute` class reference to `ModalSheetRoute`.
Use this version `modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre`

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue after upgrading flutter.
I realised that it was a compatibility issue with the flutter development environment.
Solution is to upgdate the dev channel also:

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75327201/13601462), what worked for me was, I did an override for the default modal bottom sheet using dependency override in my pubspec.yaml file by adding the following lines:

```
dependency_overrides:
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
```

(Always check indentation when adding to your pubspec.yaml file)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue temporarily by adding the below method (until the Flutter team solves this problem in the following versions).

**Add this code in `pubspec.yaml`:**

```
dependency_overrides:
  modal_bottom_sheet:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/danReynolds/modal_bottom_sheet.git
      path: modal_bottom_sheet
```